# Enable using Microsoft Visual Studio x64 tools in incredibuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, 64-bit, incredibuild

We have VS2010 pro and Incredibuild 4.62 installed. We are trying to compile to x64 platform, therefore we run 
*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xoreax\IncrediBuild\BuildConsole.exe" something.sln /MINWINVER=7 /build release|x64*

The issue is that this uses 32 bit cl.exe to compile 64 bit object files, which may be slow and runs into memory issues.

It prints to the console: Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x64 cross tools.

It should do x64 tools simply.

Comment: I've been using the method of setting the custom property in the vcxproj file as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820718/how-to-make-visual-studio-use-the-native-amd64-toolchain . This certainly seems to speed things up for me

Answer (score 0):

My name is Victor and I am from the IncrediBuild support team.

When you are building for the x64 platform in Visual Studio, by default, the compiler that is being used is actually the cross compiler located in the “x86_amd64” folder.
In order to ensure full compatibility to Visual Studio builds, IncrediBuild has to use the same compilers that are being used in Non-IncrediBuild builds.

From our experience – the 32 bit cross compiler  and the 64 bit compilers have the same speed, and we have never encountered a state where a compiler running out of memory, so using the native x64 toolset would not yield any benefits.

If however you would like to make the switch to the native x64 toolset – you need to define a new toolset with Visual Studio, which points to the x64 tools.
Once the toolset is defined, and is set to be used in the projects properties  - IncrediBuild will use it automatically.

Comment: Hey @Victor, how does one create a new toolset definition? We're running into PCB errors using the cross compiler.