# How to make Visual Studio use the native amd64 toolchain *through a .props file*

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, build, 64-bit, toolchain

According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25626630/1029366) it is possible to edit the .vcxproj file to use the 64bit tooolchain.

But I have a solution with 31 .vcxproj files!

So my question is: is it possible to edit a *common* .props file to use the 64bit toolchain?

I have tried several ways to edit the .props file without success, so please be specific in the way to edit the .props file.

Thanks in advance!

PS: in case it is relevant, I am using VS2015

Comment: It would be nice if you show some of the "several ways" you have tried.  Do you just copy-paste the tag?  If so, where did you place?

Comment: It already works this way in VS2015.  Just look at the setting to verify that it has the expected value.  Project > Properties > Platform = x64 > VC++ Directories > Executable Directories setting.  Should show $(VC_ExecutablePath_x64).