# VC compiler (Visual Studio 2015) can not link big (>2G) static lib file

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, lib

Visual Studio 2015 can not link bigger than 2G static library.

The error is:

> Can not find *.lib file.

My question is: Is it designed to? If so,why?

Comment: You are likely using the 32-bit hosted tools, You can opt-in to using the x64 native versions of the tools which should have more success. ``set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64`` and then launch ``devenv.exe`` or add ``<PropertyGroup><PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture></PropertyGroup>`` to the vcxproj right after ``Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />``. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820718/how-to-make-visual-studio-use-the-native-amd64-toolchain).

Comment: Thanks,it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32-bit tools can only use 2 GB of virtual address space (although they are `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` so technically on the 64-bit OS they can get 3 GB of virtual space). As such, the linker is likely just exhausting virtual address space on such a large library.

The solution is to use the x64 native tools instead of the 32-bit ones.

Either set an environment variable:

```
set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64
```

Or edit your vcxproj to add the following to your project file right after `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredTool‌​Architecture>
</Prope‌​rtyGroup>
```

> See [Sponsored Feature: RAM, VRAM, and More RAM: 64-Bit Gaming Is Here](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3602/sponsored_feature_ram_vram_and_.php) for the details on virtual address space limits in 32-bit vs. 64-bit apps.

Comment: A side note after trying this and succeeded: the property definition does not need to be after the `Import`. I also succeeded in putting `<PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>` in the global `PropertyGroup` before `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />`.