# Make CMake get Visual Studio build with x64 compiler and linker

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I would like to get CMake generate Visual Studio projects in a way that PreferredToolArchitecture is set to x64, so that when building in Visual Studio, x64 compiler and linker are used. The VS project file PropertyGroup for a configuration should have the PreferredToolArchitecture XML element according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683300/use-64-bit-compiler-in-visual-studio/46734431), e.g. as below

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

CMake [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET.html#variable:CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET) indicate that passing `-Tv140,host=x64` to the cmake command line should choose the x64 compiler.

However I do not see the PreferredToolArchitecture XML element in the generated project files.

Comment: Have you tried [CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_HOST_ARCHITECTURE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_HOST_ARCHITECTURE.html) variable instead? According to the docs, it is somewhat about preference.

Comment: I understand that is a readonly variable.