# Visual Studio 2022 compile error with #import <msscript.ocx>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I have a project that compiles in  VS 2019.

In Visual Studio 2022 I am getting the error:

```
C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'msscript.ocx': No such file or directory
```

Changing the import to:

```
#import <C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx>
```

instead of

```
#import <msscript.ocx>
```

seems to make things "work".

I wonder if it is related to the fact the visual studio 2022 is 64 bit now and there is some weirdness around SysWOW64.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is due to the bitness off IDE. Probably it just picks 64-bit toolset, whereas VS 2019 picks 32-bit toolset.

Comment: Maybe you need to look into this https://stackoverflow.com/q/19820718/2945027 and do the reverse